# PHP:: Fetch pure text

Tags: php, html, loops, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm courious if it's possible to fetch pure text from any html source code.

here is my simple code :

```
preg_match_all("/>(.*)</",$htmlFile,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match)
{
        highlight_string($match[0]);
}
die();
```

obviosly the problem that not everything between `>(.*)<` is a pure text.
so for example in that scenario:

```
<table style="width:100%"><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Age</th></tr><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr></table>
```

I'm expecting to get :

Firstname,Lastname,Age,Jill,Smith,50,Eve,Jackson,94

Comment: [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Use a non-greedy regexp.

Comment: DOM ............. http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard If he uses `strip_tags` everything will be combined into one long string, with no boundaries between the columns.

Comment: True @Barmar, just a suggestion. Then "pure text" is not what he is after :)

Comment: Yea, just to clarify I need to get the values into an array not just for simple output :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard He's using `preg_match_all()`, so he's trying to get each match as a separate array element.

Comment: @PUG You can simply change `.*` to `.*?` to make it non-greedy. But it would be better to use a DOM parser library rather than a regexp to process HTML.

Comment: Note that `>` is displayed as text if there's no `<`.